# Branch IO universal link is not working if pasted the url in Safari or open the link from twitter

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I'm using [branch.io](https://branch.io) to create universal links.

It's working fine but it opens applications's App Store page and not the app if I pasted the URL in safari or click it from twitter App.

If I click the link from notes app or WhatsApp, it works fine and open the app.

Comment: It should work but Can you add your clink creation code to check what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Branch.io there answer was:

This is just a twitter issue, universal links dont work sometimes on Twitter app.

Check this doc on the same:

https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-universal-links#apps-that-work-sometimes